# How to design a singleton class that needs a parameter only on the first instantiation?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, singleton

I have a singleton class, `ORMHelper`, which needs a parameter(`FileReader`) only on the first time of its instantiation.

```
ORMHelper.getInstance(FileReader fr);
```

When this is done the singleton parses the file and does its stuff. Subsequent instantiations don't need the `FileReader` as the parsing is already done.

```
ORMHelper.getInstance();
```

There is a check in the `getInstance()` to figure out if the file has already been parsed and it throws up an exception otherwise.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

When `getInstance(FileReader fr);` is invoked for the first time I would store information about the `FileReader` argument (eg: the file path it refers to). In subsequent calls to this method you could check whether the argument (respectively its underlying file) is equal to the one of the first invocation. If it is, I would not throw any exception and simply return the value of the parameterless `getInstance()` method. If the argument differs you should throw an exception.

Moreover, you should add an `isInitialized()` method which returns a boolean value indicating whether the instance has already been initialized. If you want to know if the instance is initialized it is cleaner to do the check using

```
if (ORMHelper.isInitialized()) {
  //...
}
```

than to invoke `getInstance()` and check if an exception is thrown.